jquery removeClass not removing the class
In my createdRow function for my datatable, I am trying to remove a class from the last TD. Below is the code for the function. The add class was just a test to see if the function was being fired and it seems to be because the "test" class is added to the last TD. but the remove class function doesn't remove the class. I can't seem to figure it out, I know I could (maybe) loop through the classes after it's created but I thought to use the native functions of DataTables and this is really bugging me so I want to try and figure it out.
createdRow: function(row,data,dataIndex){
 console.log(jquery(row).find("td:last")); //prints the last td in each row
 jquery(row).find("td:last").addClass("test");//this works the last TD of the table has class test
 jquery(row).find("td:last").removeClass("dt-type-date");// class is still listed in the td
 jquery(row).find("td:last")[0].removeClass("dt-type-date");//tried this as well but this gives me an error that removeClass is not a function. 
}


Instead of removeClass in your last example, try .classList.remove instead - the normal JS way. But it should work. This should be easy to turn into a working snippet?

.classList.remove does work but only after I await the completion of the datatable initialization.

There are better ways to handle this. Is the last td a date field?

@ruleboy21 yes it is a date field.

One way I was able to get it to work was to use classList.remove after awaiting the completion of the datatable initialization.
await create_modal(jQuery('#modal_table'),evt.currentTarget.querySelector('.num-description').innerText);

document.querySelectorAll('#modal_table td').forEach((td) => {
    if (td.classList.contains('dt-type-date')){
        td.classList.remove('dt-type-date');
    } 
});

